# Can you not nest Single file component tags in vue

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to nest these single file components and only the row shows. Am I not understanding this correctly?

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <row>
            <column>
                <numberModule>
            </column>
        </row>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import row from '../../containers/row.vue'
    import column from '../../containers/column.vue'
    import numberModule from '../../components/numberModuleTemplate.vue'

    const sales = {
        components: {
            row,
            column,
            numberModule
        },
    };
    export default sales;
</script>
```

*row.vue*

```html
<template>
    <row v-bind:class="classes"></row>
</template>

<script>
    const row = {
        data: function() {
            return {
                classes: ["row","row-eq-height-lg"]
            }
        }
    };

    export default row;
</script>
```

*column.vue*

```html
<template>
   <column v-bind:class="classes"></column>
</template>

<script>
    const column = {
        data: function() {
            return {
                classes: ["col-lg-3"]
            }
        }
    };

    export default column;
</script>
```

*numbersModuleTemplate.vue*

```html
<template>
    <div v-bind:id="id" v-bind:class="moduleClasses" v-cloak>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="svg-container">
                <twoPeopleOutline />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import twoPeopleOutline from "../../Views/Shared/SVGs/twoPeopleOutline.svg";

    const numberModule = {
        data: function () {
            return {
                title: "Meetings",
                id: "meetings-module",
            }
        },
        components: {
            twoPeopleOutline
        },
    };

    export default numberModule;
</script>
```

Maybe I missed something that I cant see. If I understand it correctly you should be able to nest these components but, I can only see the row showing in the dom.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Can you add row.vue, column.vue, and maybe numberModuleTemplate.vue?

Comment: I have no errors yeah I will add them now

Comment: Files added to original post

Comment: You need to add slots to your components.

Comment: Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2):

You have no [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Slot-Content) in your `<row>` so the original content is not being output.  Try:

```html
<template>
    <row v-bind:class="classes">
        <slot></slot>
    </row>
</template>

<script>
  const row = {
    data: function() {
      return {
        classes: ["row", "row-eq-height-lg"]
      }
    }
  };

  export default row;
</script>
```

The same goes for your `<column>` component as well as any other component where you want the original content that you put within the element tags to be emplaced.

Consider this simplified example demonstrating the need for `<slot>`s below:

```js
const foo = {
  template: "<div></div>"
}
const bar = {
  template: "<div><slot></slot></div>"
}

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    foo,
    bar
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <!-- Foo has no <slot> in its template -->
  <foo>Foo</foo>
  <!-- Bar does though -->
  <bar>Bar</bar>
</div>
```

Comment: Right. That's exactly what I answered 30 mins ago?

Comment: @bbsimonbb I was already working on an answer to this whenever you posted your answer.  It's OK to have multiple answers to questions.  I have upvoted your answer since it follows the same logic as mine and answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

**You absolutely can nest Vue components.** But if you want to make a component that accepts some content between it's opening and closing tags (the case for your row component), then you need to look at **[slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html)**.

[Here's your example working on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/0vpql4yrq0). I just needed to add a slot in the row component, so that `row` knows where to put the columns specified in the root template. Here's the row template...

```
<template>
    <row v-bind:class="classes">
      <slot></slot>
    </row>
</template>
```